# How to disallow specific pages in robots.txt, but allow everything else?

Tags: search, seo, robots.txt

Is this the way to do it?

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
Disallow: /a/*
```

I have pages like:

```
mydomaink.com/a/123/group/4
mydomaink.com/a/xyz/network/google/group/1
```

I don't want to allow them to appear on Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your robots.txt looks correct. You can [test in in your Google's Webmaster Tools account](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062598?hl=en) if you want to be 100% sure.

FYI, blocking pages in robots.txt doe s*not* guarantee they will not show up in the search results. It only prevents search engines from crawling those pages. They can still list them if they want to. To prevent a page from being indexed and listed you need to use the [`x-robots-tag`](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag) HTTP header.

If you use Apache you can place a file in your `/a/` directory with the following line to effectively block those pages:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-Robots-Tag: "noindex"
</IfModule>
```